# Backing up entire Ubuntu system before disk resize

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, backup

*Thanks for people pointing out that my question is too broad and hard to answer. Here is the edited question:*

**Question**: **Create an easy-to-restore system backup for Ubuntu 14.04 before resizing linux partition on a Windows-Ubuntu dual-boot system**

**Detailed requirements**:

1. Retain everything in Ubuntu partition (/home, /usr, /bin etc)
2. Be able to be restored onto a resize linux partition (larger than original) where the head of the partition is moved.
3. Easy restoration: I restore the system by "copying" or "cloning" back my backup file. I don't have to reinstall libraries, programs, or restore links, ~/.ssh ~/.bashrc or other system setup files.
4. I would prefer softwares such as Clonezilla or Déjà Dup. But I am also very happy to learn using internal utility such as tar, as long as it allows *requirement 3*.

**Current disk layout**:

500 GB disk (Partition1 + Partition 2 + Partition 3 + Partition 4)

Partition 1: Dell Utility FAT (41 MB)

Partition 2: Windows Recovery NTFS (786 MB)

Partition 3: **Windows 7 NTFS (254 GB)**

Partition 4: **Extended (246 GB)**

```
Partition 5: Filesystem Ext4 (256 GB)
Partition 6: SWAP Swap (10 GB)
```

**Desired disk layout**:

500 GB disk (Partition1 + Partition 2 + Partition 3 + Partition 4)

Partition 1: Dell Utility FAT (41 MB)

Partition 2: Windows Recovery NTFS (786 MB)

Partition 3: **Windows 7 NTFS (100 GB)**

Partition 4: **Extended (354 GB)**

```
Partition 5: Filesystem Ext4 (356 GB)
Partition 6: SWAP Swap (10 GB)
```

**Final remarks**: A brief procedure would be greatly appreciated in case I missed some important procedure and sabotage my backup process.

I hope the resizing process will just go successfully without doing restoration though.

References:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: Only use Windows to shrink the Windows NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk. Usually gparted works but sometimes Windows does not like that. And chkdsk is always required by NTFS partitions after any resize. I do not backup system, but some like the image backup and that may be better in your case. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery I backup /home, my data partition and list of installed apps. Any file manually edited in /etc is also copied into /home so it is backed up.

Comment: @oldfred This looks far more like the beginnings of a great answer than a comment IMHO. Fleshing it out with a bit more detail would definitely get it there! ;-)

Comment: You are a Crazy Frog!  **;-)** [edit] your answer, remove the unimportant questions from your question and if needed [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)! It's not like we charge you by the amount of questions you ask! (but we *do not* like questions that are **too broad to answer**.  **;-) :P**

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your help.  you have a good point in using shrinking disk in windows disk management. I am pretty sure that's the safest way to retain both OSs. I did also think about backup different folders of ubuntu instead of the entire system. However, I aim for an option for a fast and hassle-free restoration of the system so I searched for whole system backup. But it is still very helpful of your comment and I appreciate it!

Comment: @Fabby Lol. I know the question is long but they are all related. My demand created this special back-up requirement. And because of all existing but different back up questions on this site, I meant to provide enough details so people would know exactly what I am asking about. There is really only one question though. But I edited it so it is more clear and logic. I also deleted the minor question regarding retaining customization.  Thanks for your critics.

Comment: So?  Did the answer help?  If yes, read last comment... STP?  :P

Answer (score 2):

You ask a lot of questions in ... well.. one question.  This site works best if you ask one question per question, therefore I will only answer one of your questions:

The VeryEasyWay™ to do this is to use [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) as long as you:

- turn off hibernation in Windows
- save the [CloneZilla disk-to-image](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) to an external, removable drive
- set a `chkdsk /f x:` for all your disks and *then shut down*
- use [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) to resize
- first boot Windows, then Ubuntu

Comment: Don't use gparted to resize Windows/NTFS partitions. Windows won't like that. Use Windows own Disk Management app, and then reboot after.

Comment: Clonezilla has one **big** flaw. On **clone** operations, it will only work if the destination drive is **bigger** than the source drive (even by 1 block). Which means that **you can never restore to the original source drive**. I don't know if **disk-to-image** has the same flaw.

Comment: @heynnema: that's why you should execute chkdsk before shutting down: done it hundreds of times, and no disk2img doesn;t have that flaw.

Comment: Edited as you commented :D Thanks for the answer. One question: When I backup the Ubuntu partition, do I get to backup the upper level partition 4  or I have to backup lower level partition 5 and partition 6 separately? Thanks.

Comment: @CrazyFrog you don't clone individual partitions: you clone *the entire disk* to an image that is compressed in memory before being written to disk as to give you a file that fits onto a much smaller disk.  (compression depends on the type of files you have)

Comment: Please don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**